# Point Sampling Tool pyQGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, point, sampling

I have several raster files (raster_1, raster_2, [...], raster_n) and a point shapefile. The point shapefile (point.shp) was created using "generatepointspixelcentroidsinsidepolygons" so my points are located at the center of each raster pixel.

```
processing.runalg('qgis:generatepointspixelcentroidsinsidepolygons',".../raster_1.tif","input.shp", "point.shp")
```

My goal is to extract raster_n value to each point. This is possible using the point sampling tool plugin. However I want to use the python command on QGIS.

There must be a solution similar to:

```
processing.runald('qgis:pointsamplingtool',"raster_1","raster_2","raster_n","point.shp","output.shp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very efficient solution using R. Please find it attached below.

```
library(raster)
raster1 <- raster("/path/input1.tif")
raster2 <- raster("/path/input2.tif")
raster3 <- raster("/path/input3.tif")
rastern <- raster("/path/inputn.tif")
rasStack = stack(raster1, raster2, raster3, rastern)
pointCoordinates=read.csv("/path/point.csv")
coordinates(pointCoordinates)=~lat+lon
rasValue=extract(rasStack,pointCoordinates)
combinePointValue=cbind(pointCoordinates,rasValue)
write.table(combinePointValue,file="output.csv",append=FALSE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE)
```

Hope that will help

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS >= 3.4 you can use the "qgis:rastersampling"  algorithm.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, however I am using QGIS 2.18.15. I found an efficient solution using R. See response.

Comment: I love the simplicity of qgis:rastersampling, and use it within the Py console. 

However,  I'm having trouble running it in an external PyQGIS script though, since it cannot find the processing algorithm I'm trying to run:
processing.run("qgis:rastersampling", params)

I can run any ("native") processing algorithm easily by adding QgsNativeAlgorithms() via the following line: 
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

But I'm not sure how to add a similar line to add any of the "qgis" processing algorithms. 
Any ideas?