# Raster layer stacking and extracting values at points with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, sampling

I have a dozen single band raster layers in the same CRS overlapping perfectly. I would like to 'stack them one on the other' and extract values at point locations (from a CSV).

After that the values of the single rasters should be added to a new generated point shapefile (or CSV).

In QGIS I would use the **Point samplint tool plug-in** for that purpose but I need to develop an automated process.

A similar question was asked here [Point Sampling Tool pyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308708/point-sampling-tool-pyqgis) with no satisfying answer for my task.

I have started as follows but I can't go beyond it now; my coding skills are exhausted.

```
### Path to raster folder ###

os.chdir('Path_to_folder_with_Raster_Layers')
rast = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) 



##### Loop over folder for .tif files ###

for ras in rast:
    if '.tif' in ras:
        if 'aux' not in ras:
            print(ras)



###### Load Points ####

pts = "file:///Path_to_folder.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=decimalLongitude&yField=decimalLatitude"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(pts,'Points','delimitedtext')
```

I also tried to create a VRT out of the rasters:

```
gdal.BuildVRT('VRT_Raster.vrt', ras)
```

but what I got is just a single band VRT with the sum of all raster cell values.

How can I extract the raster values of multiple rasters at point locations and write that information to a new created point shapefile (or CSV)?